# Augmenting a TypeScript Module

Tags: typescript, sinon

I'm trying to augment the Sinon type definition for our project, here's how the `Sinon.d.ts` is defined

```
declare module 'sinon' {
  module Sinon {
    interface SinonStub extends SinonSpy {
      ...
    }
    interface SinonStatic { ... }
    ...
  }

  var Sinon: Sinon.SinonStatic;

  export = Sinon;
}
```

I have a `definitions.d.ts` which I use in my project for any custom definitions. Here's how I tried to do it:

```
declare module 'sinon' {
  module Sinon {
    interface SinonPromise {
      resolves(value?: any): void;
      rejects(value?: any): void;
    }

    interface SinonStub {
      returnsPromise(): SinonPromise;
    }
  }
}
```

But the compiler does not recognize the new `returnsPromise` in the `SinonStub` interface, nor does it recognize the new `SinonPromise` type.

What's wrong with that definition?

Comment: I've got the same problem when writing the definitions for `sinon-as-promised` and `sinon-mongoose` when I've used typings to get the npm definitions.

Comment: N.B. Modules (internal modules) are discouraged in TypeScript, they are recommending ES6 JavaScript modules (external modules or just modules) instead of the old namespace based one. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html and https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces-and-modules.html

Comment: @JuanMendes that does not help, I didn't produce the typings for sinon, I'm using them and need to augment with some custom functions.

Comment: What was the source of the `sinon` typings? They differ from those that I have installed.

Comment: @cartant I have installed them using the typings tool ... that's all

Answer (score 1):

I believe your case requires a workaround. The definition file you have does not `export` any type definitions, so they can't be extended outside of that file.

I'm guessing that you installed `sinon` via `typings install sinon`. If you do `typings search sinon` there are actually 2, one from `npm` and one from `dt`. The default installs the `npm` definitions. This is what the [`dt` definition](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/6f5c53028aaeb2f9e184561f4bf70eaa22a351c3/sinon/sinon.d.ts) looks like:

```
declare namespace Sinon {
  // ...
  interface SinonStub extends SinonSpy {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}

declare var sinon: Sinon.SinonStatic;

declare module "sinon" {
  export = sinon;
}
```

There is also a `dt` entry for [sinon-stub-promise](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd/sinon-stub-promise/sinon-stub-promise.d.ts), which plays nicely with the above:

```
declare namespace Sinon {
  interface SinonPromise {
    resolves(value?: any): void;
    rejects(value?: any): void;
  }

  interface SinonStub {
    returnsPromise(): SinonPromise;
  }
}
```

So, this is the workaround:

1. Remove the current `sinon` typing.
2. Install the DefinitelyTyped typings for `sinon`: `typings install sinon --source dt --global`
3. Install the DefinitelyTyped typings for `sinon-stub-promise`: `typings install sinon-stub-promise --source dt --global`

This now successfully compiles:

```
/// <reference path="typings/index.d.ts" />

import * as sinon from 'sinon';

sinon.stub().returnsPromise();
```